# jquery reset conditional filter

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have 2 dropdown lists on my webform and using jquery trying to filter/reset filter 2nd dropdown elements based on 1st dropdown selection.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
       $('#dropdown1').change(function(e)
       {
            switch ($(this).val())
            {
                 case "4":
                 //this removal works
                 $('#dropdown2').filter(function()
                    {
                        return ($(this).val() == 16);

                    }).remove();
                    break;


                 .................    
                 default:
                 //how would I restore filter here? 

            }

       }

});
```

Removing part works, so it filters item with no problem, but I have difficulty restoring the filter on dropdown 2 if something else is chosen in dropdown 1. I was trying to use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of `.remove()` but it doesn't seem to work on IE6 at least.

Comment: Can you read the original values into an array when the page loads? And then just reset all of the values?

Comment: Just read all the values from dropdown 2 into Array?

Comment: Could you show in general terms how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of your document ready take a copy of the values in dropdown2 like this:

```
var drp2values = $('#dropdown2').html();
```

then whenever you want to reset the values in dropdown2 to its original state do this:

```
$('#dropdown2').html(drp2values);
```

The actual value in the var will be something like :

```
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
```

just tried it:

This code works:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var drp2values = $('#dropdown2').html();

       $('#dropdown1').change(function(e)
       {
            switch ($(this).val())
            {
                 case "4":
                 //this removal works...  now ;)
                 $('#dropdown2').find('option').filter(function()
                    {
                    alert('in4 filt' + drp2values + $(this).val());
                        return ($(this).val() == 16);

                    }).remove();
                    break;  
                 default:
                 //how would I restore filter here? 
                 $('#dropdown2').html(drp2values);
            }

       });

});
```

With this HTML

```
<BODY>
    <select id='dropdown1'>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select id='dropdown2'>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
    </select>
</BODY>
```

The original code you posted where you said the remove worked, it didnt remove the individual option with value 16, it removed the entire dropdown as you were not geting the options before you filtered, you were removing the dropdown :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Nice, simple concise with code explanation...welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was just my typo, I don't delete dropdown normally:-)